# Convert char date AM/PM to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I have a column dataframe (`sleep$Time`) with a format like this:

```r
time <- data.frame(sleep = c("4/27/2016 12:00:00 AM",
                             "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM",
                             "5/16/2016 12:00:00 AM",
                             "5/11/2016 12:00:00 AM"))
```

There are around 300 rows with a `character` format.

I have try:

```r
sleep$Time <- parse_date_time(sleep$Time, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") #date is returned as POSIXct but the time is gone

sleep$Time <- as.POSIXct(sleep$Time, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") #date is returned as POSIXct but the time is gone

sleep$Time <- strptime(sleep$SleepDay, format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p") #return NA
```

Is there any other way that I can try?

Comment: Conversion format is OK : `as.POSIXct("4/27/2016 11:59:59 AM", format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")` works as expected. 12 AM is midnight so becomes 00:00:00, try 12 PM

Comment: `4/27/2016 12:00:00 AM` is not existing, 12h clock goes from 0 AM to 1-11 AM to 12 PM to 1-11 PM

Comment: It is a sample data with the all same hour 12:00:00 AM. I am using -->
sleep$Time <- format(strptime(sleep$SleepDay, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%I:%M:%S")
to take away the time then use the sleep$Time <- parse_date_time(sleep$Time, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") to change it to POSIXct. Is there any other way around?